# Ubuntu Server: Apache Fonts Issue

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, apache2, font-size

I am working on Ubuntu Server and I am using apache2 for my webserver. At the moment I am first working on my laptop which is running on Windows with XAMPP and when I style a page with a simple font-family like Arial and font-size: 70% for example, when I look at it at Chrome it looks perfect. However when I upload it on my server and look it from there the font is not applied and the size of the navigation and everything is a bit bigger.

Is there a configuration about apache2 that i missed ? Do u need to configre it to use fonts or maybe an exact path to see which fonts are installed and use them ? I dunno, please someone to help if they are aware of the problem

Cheers : )